# unaccessable user?

Tags: dolphin

its been almost two days since I've installed KDE ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10.
I've 3 drive partitions in my windows and a 32 gigs root drive partition in my linux.
when i seek properties of drives and files inside it i see owner has rwx permissions but i a unable to create files and folders, move or delete files and paste files from my root downloads folder
i installed nautilus and dolphin file explorers but they both behave the same
it'd be great if someone helped at an instance

Comment: Your filesystem is possibly mounted read-only. Do `df <directory with problems>` to find the filesystem the directory belongs to and then `cat /proc/mounts` or `findmnt <filesystem>` to display the mount options.

Comment: `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld` will help you explore permissions/ownerships.